# Xively:Trigger url Web Service does not get called

Tags: triggers, xively

I am working on Xively.

I have created 3 (A,B,C)channels. Requirement is whenever there is any change in channel value, my web service should get called.

But due to some unknown reason with "Send Test Trigger" button as well as with actual condition met trigger does not get called.I have tested my Web service it is working with non-xively interface.

Any suggestion what is the reason behind this issue.

P.S. -My app is in Develop stage

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you mange to fix this? I'm struggling with the same problem.

Comment: It was issue with network proxy

Answer (score 2):

I have tried out some test triggers, both with "Send Test Trigger" and by sending a new value to the channel with a trigger. Both of these worked fine and instantly for me, so I don't think that your problem is on the Xively end.

My recommendation would be to try using a http://requestb.in/ bin in order to debug the trigger, try sending it then and see if it shows up in the requestb.in this could suggest that there is problem with the trigger bing received by your web service. Without seeing how you are trying to receive the trigger, that is the only suggestion I can make.